# Oppo F1s stuck at Boot logo or Bootloop

Tags: boot-loop

I flashed Stock Rom on my Oppo F1 using Sp Flash tool. software indicate green right but phone didn't boot. Now what i have to do? how to solve this

Comment: what rom did you flash?